# how can we increase or decrease the size of div on btn click in asp.net?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

how can we increase or decrease the size of div on btn click in asp.net?

stylesheet

```
<style>
div{
    width:50px; 
    height:70px; 
    float:left; 
    margin:5px; 
    background:rgb(255,140,0); 
}
</style>
```

Javascript:

```
<script src="_http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
$("div").one('click', function () {
    $(this).height(30);
});
</script>
```

Markup:

```
<body>
    <div></div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is this `.one(` of which you reference in your code.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss - It's a way to attach an event handler that executes at most one time: http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: I suspect this is caused by an extra `_` at the start of your `<script...` include, as [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2qHv3/) which is taken directly from your example works as expected!

Comment: @Jamiec - thanks, don't know how I ever missed that one, learned something here!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("div").click(function() { $(this).height(30); });
```

***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CodeMaverick/pJWMh/)***

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<input type="button" id="aAdd"  value="Increase" />
<input type="button" id="aDecrease"  value="Decrease" />
```

**Script**

```
var currentHeight;
var measurement=100;

$(function(){    
    currentHeight=$("#div1").height();  
    $("#aAdd").click(function(){      
        currentHeight=parseInt(currentHeight)+measurement    
        $("#div1").height(currentHeight);
    });
     $("#aDecrease").click(function(){     
        currentHeight=parseInt(currentHeight)-measurement             
        $("#div1").height(currentHeight);
    });

});
```

Here is the working sample http://jsfiddle.net/pJWMh/14/

Answer (score -2):

Fist of all you have give id for div. i have modify some html and place button as below.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="dvMain">
</div>

<input id="btn" onclick="javascript:changeDivSize();" type="button" value="Change Size" />

</form>
```

call javascript functin changeDivSize() as below

```
function changeDivSize() {

        $("#dvMain").height(500);
    }
```

Hope this will help you...

Comment: no one "has to add an id" and I consider it bad practice to add behavior to markup with the `onclick` this way as my preference.  You also added additional (perhaps non-existent) markup.